# Postgres EXECUTE with CTE

Tags: postgresql, prepared-statement, common-table-expression

Is it possible to EXECUTE a prepared statement using parameters you'd get from a CTE ?

The below samples are simplified versions of my code, but this is replicating exactly the problem I have.

Here's how far I've been able to go - without a CTE :

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE testTable
(
    col1 NUMERIC,
    col2 TEXT
) ON COMMIT DROP;

INSERT INTO testTable
VALUES (1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar');

PREPARE myStatement AS
    WITH cteTable AS
    (
        SELECT col1, col2
        FROM testTable
        WHERE col1 = $1
    )
    SELECT col2 FROM cteTable;


EXECUTE myStatement(2);

DEALLOCATE myStatement;
COMMIT;
```

Here's the result:

> col2
>
> ---
>
> bar

And now, here's what I am trying to achieve :

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE testTable
(
    col1 NUMERIC,
    col2 TEXT
) ON COMMIT DROP;

INSERT INTO testTable
VALUES (1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar');

PREPARE myStatement AS
    WITH cteTable AS
    (
        SELECT col1, col2
        FROM testTable
        WHERE col1 = $1
    )
    SELECT col2 FROM cteTable;

-- Using a CTE here to get the parameters for the prepared statement
WITH parameters AS
(
    SELECT 2 val
)
EXECUTE myStatement(SELECT val FROM parameters);

DEALLOCATE myStatement;
COMMIT;
```

The error message I'm having is

> Syntax error at or near EXECUTE

Even if try to run the EXECUTE part without attempting to use the CTE values, I still have the same error message.

As I haven't been able to find anyone else having the same issue despite my researches, I guess I could be doing it wrong.. If so could someone please point me into the right direction ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid you can't use execute prepared statement in query

Comment: But you can have a subselect as argument, right?

Comment: sorry - it sounds confusing - like subquery as prepared statement argument, which Is not possible - right? unless I totally don't understand:) late time. `prepare s(int) as select $1; execute s((select 3));` won't work

Answer (score 0):

As [Vao Tsun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5315974/vao-tsun) commented, this is not possible.

I have converted my prepared statement to a function which will return a table, then used a CTE to SELECT UNION my function with multiple parameters.